# Create promql query with load all cpu

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have an open endpoint to get the metric and I don't know if it is possible to create a request that loads all the CPU and shuts down the server.

Comment: So youre saying someone could use this endpoint to make a DOS attack on your server? what about the other endpoints youer server provides? Coulnt they be used better for a DOS attack?

Comment: Other endpoints close, only Prometheus ui access without auth and failtoban.

Comment: What’s hindering you to add an authentication infrontbof your prometheus endpoint and IP filtering, so that only your prometheus can access?